# Android stop textview from increasing it's size

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

I have a quick question... I'm trying to make small test app for android just to see what it can do... So.. On start android sets textview.text to some text from shared prefs and increases textview size vertically.. I can't understand why.. I'm using tableview with the row of textviews in each row..
[image]

The xml code looks something like this:

```
 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="5.1"
            android:background="#F8F8FF"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </TableRow>
```

Is there anyway to stop that textview from resizing? Or there is some attribute I have missed..?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on your TableRow you have

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

change to a fix height or to some relative height with "layout_weight".

If you say to android wrap to content, the rows will increase/decrease to fit his content.

**Edit:** i see your layout_weight, but you have 1, i think you don't know how to use it. weight repart the width and height with this weight, so think, you have 5 rows so if 1 is the total weight 1/5=>0.2 will be your weight per row.
To the weight will apply, you need to say which dimension is based on weight.
so you need to put this

```
 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >
```

You can read more here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: If I set fixed height, will it adjust itself accordingly to a different screen size?

Comment: yes if you use dp example:layout_height="30dp". You can see this with differents emulators sizes

Comment: I edit my comment, take a look, will be better than setting fix height

Comment: Instead of setting it to a fixed DIP, you could use the DisplayMetrics to programmatically set it to a height based on the percentage of the screen size at runtime. You can access the width/height pixels via getResources().getDisplayMetrics().withPixels or heightPixels, respectively. E.g. setting it to 25% of the overall height would be (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * .25)

Comment: Woow.. That's complicated... I'll try that one also.. )))  Thanks again!!

Comment: @Guardanis Yeah!, but i ever prefer to use weight, the Visual part stay on the xml

Comment: Weights work really well when you have a layout that you want to specifically conform to the screen, but when it comes to content that you may want (or need) scrolled, using percentages can be very advantageous